# Select and order by an union

Tags: mysql, union

Is it possible to:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 , table2 ORDER BY (a UNION)
```

I tried that but doesn't work.

I looked on Google for some answers but got nothing and I don't know how to look anymore, what to search so this is my last solution: ask here. Maybe one of you knows a clause I don't and would help in my case. I don't know how else to think this query...

The union is made between two columns from two tables (or more). So i want to order every possible row by this new column made with union. Something like (so this will be generic) :

```
SELECT * FROM table1 , table2 ORDER BY ((SELECT col1 AS col FROM table1) UNION ALL (SELECT col2 AS col FROM table2) ORDER BY col DESC);
```

Comment: What do you mean by `ORDER BY (a UNION)` can you please give an example?

Comment: It was a generic question. I want to find out if it is actually possible to order rows from two or more tables by the union of two columns from two (or more) tables.

Comment: In normal SQL I would expect you'd need to join the tables to each other, and select from the result of the combination, ordering by whichever column you needed.

Answer (score 1):

Try this query like that :-

```
SELECT * FROM(
SELECT * FROM table1
UNION 
SELECT * FROM table2
) as tab ORDER BY col_name
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do the `union` and then `order`, you can do:

```
select t1.*
from table1 t1 
union
select t2.*
from table2 t2
order by a;
```

Notes:

- Use `union all` rather than `union`, unless you specifically want to incur the overhead of removing duplicates.
- The use of  `*` implies that the two tables have the same columns in the same order (and compatible types).